# How to share common files for android and ios in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have some csv files which will be used by android Native UI component. Right now its on android's Resource folder.

Now I'm gonna start working on ios Native UI component part so should I have to duplicate the files ? Or is there any way to have a shared resources. So I don't have to update the same file twice.